# How can He reign over no subjects? [אדון עולם אשר מלך בטרם כל יצור נברא]

Tags: tefilla, mysticism-kabbalah, theology, chabad

אדון עולם אשר מלך בטרם כל יצור

How can He have "reigned" over no one? Shouldn't another term have been used?

אין מלך בלא עם !

(I'd also like to hear an explanation from Chassidus.)

---

*Possible explanations I came across online, are any correct?*

1. The "potential" that God has to create beings at any time.
2. God's kingship is seen as independent and absolute, stemming from His infinite power and dominion. The act of creation is then viewed as an expression of this existing kingship.
3. From God's eternal perspective, creation and His reign as king may be conceived as a single, unified act, blurring the line between before and after.

---

*Discussion in Hebrew on this topic:*

(My hebrew is not great.)

https://tora-forum.co.il/threads/%D7%90%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A-%D7%91%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A8-%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90.41982/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Hashem reign alone?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/134293/will-hashem-reign-alone). I understand if you feel that this question is different, as in theory it is, but the answers there answer your question, which is a common cause for closing a question as a dupe.

Comment: @RabbiKaii I skimmed your answer there but did not notice anything about a king. I will look into it deeper if you tell me there is something there mentioning about how he can be a King without any subjects. (Or does the term Melech mean something else here?)

Comment: Well, the maskana from my answer there is that this question is possibly flawed because "alone" means He and His subjects became united. To tackle that question from another angle, consider what the Rebbe writes [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'ar_HaEmunah_VeYesod_HaChasidut%2C_Entrance_to_the_Gate_of_Beit_Yaakov.5.9?vhe=Shaar_HaEmunah_Ve%27Yesod_HaChassidut,_1996.&lang=bi&with=About&lang2=he). שאם היה ברצון הש"י להקרא מלך, אז, היה כביכול בהכרח לברוא את העולם שאין מלך בלא עם. אבל באמת זה הוא דעת נברא, אבל מצד מלכות הש"י יש מלך בלא עם ומלך בטרם כל יציר נברא מאחר שהכל בידו:

Comment: @RabbiKaii so is he a king because he has the potential to be a king and rule over people? Even though he might not be doing it at the moment?

Comment: [Lets take this to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150926/how-can-he-reign-alone-chat)

Comment: The essence of existence before Hashem created our world was *malchus*.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE that's my question. How? In what way? Over who is he being a melech?

Comment: @larry909 The most basic assumption in all thought is that a thing can define itself, since if a thing cannot define itself then nothing else can define it either. This means that the ability to self-define must have been created prior to the rest of the *briah*. The essential purpose of *malchus* is to ensure the integrity of that which exists within the *malchus* so that it can exist in a predictable and orderly fashion. I.e. to allow that which exists in the *malchus* to be self-defined. So the essential  nature of *malchus* is a prerequisite to the *briah*.

Comment: Why do we assume the verse means there are no subjects? I've always understood it to mean there are no co-rulers or sub-rulers.

Comment: @ClintEastwood the assumption is based on the accepted theory that אין מלך בלא עם